# How to Get Dns host name from ldap connection?

Tags: c#, dns, ldap

Is it possible to get the dns host server name of an LDAP connection? 
I am using SSL and LDAP connection from DirectoryServices.Protocols, I know it is possible by using the PrincipalContext but I can't use that.

If anyone knows please let me know =)

Comment: Why can't you use PrincipalContext?

Comment: It's a matter of design, I already have implemented everything with the DirectoryServices.Protocols, and the only change I need to make is to retrieve the dnsHostServer name from the  ldapConnection object.

Answer (score 2):

LDAP, is a protocol, and has no abilities to provide DNS resolution UNLESS, the DNS entries are present within the LDAP Server Implementation.

And often but not always, Microsoft Active Directory, does contain the DNS records.

I found [this article](http://codeidol.com/active-directory/active-directory/DNS-and-DHCP/Introduction/) that appears to be STILL be valid.

So if your Microsoft Domain is using the built in DNS information is exposed in Microsoft Active Directory at:

```
DC=<ZoneName>,cn=MicrosoftDNS,cn=System,<DomainDN>
```

Sorry, I am not very familiar with c#.